# xsd2java - no.nils.wsdl2java

Tags: gradle, xsd, jaxb2, wsdl2java

I am following below tutorial to generate Xsd2Java using gradle

https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java

I would like to know how can i pass command line argument to ant.xjc task.

Here is my example but seems it's not taking my 3 argument ([extension: true], [value: '-Xtbs'] )

```
xsd2java {
   def contractDir = "$buildDir/extractedContracts"
   File perContract = new File("$contractDir/Enterprise.xsd")
   File adContract = new File("$contractDir/AdFpc.xsd")
   File adListContract = new File("$contractDir/AdListData.xsd")

  xsdsToGenerate = [
   [file("$perContract"), 'com.performance.contract',[extension: true], [ value: '-Xtbs']],
   [file("$adContract"), 'ad.contract',[extension: true],[value: '-Xtbs']],
   [file("$adListContract"), 'ad.list.contract',[extension: true], [value: '-Xtbs']],
  ]
  generatedXsdDir = file(project.ext.generatedSrcDir)
}
```

-xtbs generate toString , hashcode and equals method

does anyone have any suggestion or example of xsd2java

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how can i pass command line argument to ant.xjc task.

In the [description of the ant-task for xjc](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.0.2/docs/xjcTask.html) you can find the following, quote:

> **arg**
>
> Additional command line arguments passed to the XJC. For details about the syntax, see the [relevant section in the Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg). This nested element can be used to specify various options not natively supported in the xjc Ant task. For example, currently there is no native support for the following xjc command-line options:
>
> - nv
> - use-runtime
> - schema
> - dtd
> - relaxng
> - Xlocator
> - Xsync-methods

Ini that [*relevant section*](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg) mentioned above, there are enough examples that explain how you can do this.